# Deleting specific variables from memory where some vars are not initialized (try-except)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables, memory

If a user has a long list of specific variables (e.g. 1000 vars) that they wish to clear from memory, but where some of the variables might not have been initialized (or already cleared), is there a more space-efficient way to handle this than a very long list of `try`-`except` commands?

Example:

```
try:
  del query_1_coents
except:
  pass
try:
  del query_1_coents_copy
except:
  pass
try:
  del query_1_ents
except:
  pass
try:
  del query_1_ents_copy
except:
  pass
try:
  del query_1_native_copy
except:
  pass
try:
  del query_1_native_words
except:
  pass
try:
  del query_1_native_words_copy
except:
  pass
try:
  del query_1_translated_copy
except:
  pass
try:
  del query_1_translated_words
except:
  pass
```

Comment: "If a user has a long list of specific variables (e.g. 1000 vars) "... There is *never* a good reason for this to be the case. How exactly did you find yourself in this situation? I would fix the source of whatever is producing this madness rather than trying to work around it. What do you mean by "a list of variables" anyway? `list` objects *hold other objects* not variables... it seems to me you should have been using some sort of *container* to begin with.

Comment: @juanpa: Yep, sounds like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Jonathan: Generally speaking the cause of the problem sounds like it's due having "a list of specific variables" — by which I assume you mean their _names_. An alternative container like a dictionary with these names as keys associated with some current value (or `None` if there isn't one) would avoid what you're asking about because it would allow you to work generically.with each entry in the dictionary via a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you all - to answer the questions above, it's caused by many layers of iteration with many sub-branches of operations (a process tree). 

Whether or not a branch is created depends on user input choices (params in an interface). As the steps in the interface are sequential, rerunning a process in the middle of the interface leaves a number of cached results. 

Wiping all variable assignment with iPython's %reset is not an option as it will wipe the earlier processes' variables too.

Comment: @martineau - thank you - is there a "best practice" to manage variables in a dictionary that you would recommend? (I'm not sure this is an XY problem - as the question contains X as an example and specifically asks if there is a better Y?).

Comment: Since the data would be in a dictionary, it already has a well defined interface. You could, of course, implement some kind "database" class with methods that do the management and enforce any "rules" there may be with respect using to them. As a bonus, it could (and probably should) hide how the details of how database is being implemented.

Comment: Q: Are all these variables defined at the module-level if they exist?